# The Cypress test does not open the Powerapps page

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

I'm trying to run simple cypress test and get error like this:
[image]

but if i change visit url to another - it opens normally:

[image]
I cant understand why this does this error come with this url:

```
"baseUrl":"https://apps.powerapps.com/play/f1t75er8-03c9-4cc7-996d-6743cd7eac4a"
```

another visible error:

[image]

code:

```
describe("Create request",  () => {
    it("Should have a link that navigates to office365 login",  () => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.get('div[class="loginNeededText_uf5ohz"]').contains('Sign in to start using Power Apps');
      });
    });
```

**P.S. Also can't load https://apps.powerapps.com/ page. Error:**

[image]

Comment: How are you authenticating ?

Comment: What i should to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In general

With Cypress, you should not try to [*visit or interact with sites or servers you do not control*](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Visiting-external-sites). The main purpose of Cypress is testing, so when you try to do anything else with it, the task will become significantly more complicated (you can read more about it in [the Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Permanent-trade-offs-1)).

If you really need information from a 3rd party site, it is recommended you do it through an API — mainly with the `cy.request()` method (e.g., Microsoft has quite an extensive documentation on how to work with the [Office 365 Management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/)).

## Your case

When you visit the *apps.powerapps.com*, you are being redirected to the Microsoft login page — it has a different domain name, which breaks a [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) causing the cross-origin error in the Cypress console.

Seems that the page you specified in the `baseUrl` returns a `404` status code, along with some ugly CORS errors in the console, which suggest an issue with the app itself. After you solved those, you would most probably face the need of authentication anyway, and it is better to do it through an API.

Answer (score 1):

When I use your base URL https://apps.powerapps.com/play/f1t75er8-03c9-4cc7-996d-6743cd7eac4a I see only blank screen and 404 error in the console, I am not redirected to login.

Maybe your URL should be https://apps.powerapps.com and after you login you can navigate to "/play/f1t75er8-03c9-4cc7-996d-6743cd7eac4a".

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I changed url to https://apps.powerapps.com, but still can't load. I added an image to the description.

Comment: Try to make the baseURL https://make.powerapps.com/, as your current URL redirects to it.

Comment: You can also have a look at the CORS headers in PowerApps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/cors-support

Comment: still the same :/ can't load the page.